# How to use matrix postTranslate() Method To Set Text At particular position for all phones?

Tags: android, xml

I would like to set my sticker at a specific position using this:

```
sticker.getMatrix().postTranslate(210, -100);
```

But it is changing for all devices.

How can I set it properly?

Comment: I'm talking about sticker view ..

Comment: yes it is library